# How to change mobile device screen size in Unity for testing?

Tags: unity, viewport

For an experiment I need to be able to dynamically adjust the screen size of my device. I'm using a Nexus 5 (5") and want to fake the screensize to 2", 3", 4",.. See images:

[image]

[image]

Is this possible using Unity? I'm aware that I can easily place some planes right in front of my camera, but I'm looking for a proper solution.

Comment: You can set any screen resolution in the editor for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the camera background color to black and make your game play in the specified area and then programmatically change the settings of camera like size etc.
You can find more information on how to play with camera here: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.html

Answer (score 4):

In the editor's Game view, you can set the size that you'll see when you hit Play. Across the top of that view are buttons for screen resolution; the far left side has setting for screen size, and the right side has Maximize on Play.

Comment: as a side note , it will only work if the resolution you are targeting is smaller than the desktop resolution, otherwise there is no way as far as i know. So testing for Ipads retina display will be a problem if you don't have a 4k display.